# "Restart" number after 360

Tags: php

I know this isn't EXACTLY a programming question, but I need help in my (php) code and I will explain it in the simplest way I can (Without code).

I have a variable that goes from 0 to 720 and I want, that the number begins from 0 after 360.

Like this:

```
0 = 0
1 = 1
2 = 2
...
359 = 359
360 = 0 (or 360)
361 = 1
...
719 = 359
720 = 0 (or 360)
```

Im scratching my head about this. I know, that's easy, I even made it many times before, but i just can't remember it. I also googled about it and searched on StackOverflow. I don't find it, because I don't know exactly what I should type to come to my solution. "Restarting" a number doesn't exist, but I can't imagine a better tag for my question - for now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code that builds this wand explain what you want to do? Count the number of 360 rotations?

Comment: @chris85 Okay, let's go: I made a SVG image with php, that draws a circle, and that circle moves forward. It goes from 0 to 720 (sometimes even bigger, but it's always dividible by 360), and I made some code that analyses the angle of the current dot. It looks if the circle is between 0 and 10 and then print something out, but this will ony work, if I restart after 359... The actual variable I cannot change, and I don't want to use another. There's a way, a simple mathematical function, I believe.

Comment: `%` [Modulus operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).... `$x = 999; $x %= 360; echo $x;`

Comment: @MarkBaker THAT WAS AWESOME! Thank you. Post it as an answer, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `%` [Modulus operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)....

```
$x = 999;
$x %= 360;
echo $x;
```

Comment: @Fusseldieb - there is a big difference between the operator (which works with integer values) and the `fmod()` function that works with floats

Comment: What's the diference? It won't work with Integers? Only Floats? Or will it give a wrong result?

Comment: The % operator will adjust to integers as needed, and is a lot more efficient because of this (no float arithmetic, no function call overhead), whereas fmod() accepts float arguments and will always return a float - https://3v4l.org/LsQn5 - but you can find yourself getting different results if you use them inappropriately

Comment: Understood now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to return a number instead of changing the variable:

```
function check360($number) {
    if($number < 360) return $number;
    return 360 % $number;
}
```

You can add another check to return false if `$number >= 720` if you want.